# Don't display 404 in console after $.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I'm dynamically accessing resources on my server through `$.get()`.
Sometimes the requested file doesn't exist and I get a 404 which I handle through `.error()`.

My problem is, that the error is still displayed in the browsers console. How can I prevent that?

I tried `try{} catch(e) {}` as well, but jQuery throws the error anyways.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Also why is that a problem?

Comment: Even gmail has 1k+ error in their browsers console

Comment: I think it isn't a very good sign to see so many errors in the console, so I try to prevent them.
Maybe there is an easy way to prevent this, which I just didn't find.